# why jupyter is coming up name not defined

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, undefined, probability

hi im doing work on jupyter for probability and when i went to run this piece of code it keeps coming up
'''name 'bag_2' is not defined'''.
this seemed to work for me for days leading up to this and i have changed nothing about it so dont understand. thanks

```
    import random

    bag = ['bag_1', 'bag_2']
    print(random.choice(bag))

    if bag == 'bag_1':
        colour = 'white', 'black'
        print(random.choices(bag_1, weights=(30, 70), k = 1))
    else:
        colour = 'white', 'black'
        print(random.choices(bag_2, weights=(60, 40), k = 1))
```

Comment: Did you think you had defined a `bag_2` variable somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `bag` is a list containing the strings 'bag_1' and 'bag_2'. So, your `if` statement is always false (i.e. the notebook always execute the `else` statement). This happens because the function `print(random.choice(bag))` shows in the output tab either 'bag_1' or 'bag_2', but it doesn't assign that value to the variable `bag`, which remains a list.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, a solution could be to define a second variable such as `bag_chosen`.

```
import random

bag = ['bag_1', 'bag_2']
bag_chosen = random.choice(bag)
print(bag_chosen) # in case you still want to print the chosen bag

if bag_chosen == 'bag_1':
    colour = 'white', 'black'
    print(random.choices(colour, weights=(30, 70), k = 1))
else:
    colour = 'white', 'black'
    print(random.choices(colour, weights=(60, 40), k = 1))
```

This code randomly chooses a bag from the list and, depending on which bag came out, chooses a colour according to the specified weights.